# Why is an exception no longer considered to have occurred after being thrown?

Tags: javascript, exception, ecmascript-5

In [5.2 Algorithm Conventions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-5.2) of the ECMAScript® Language Specification 5.1 Edition:

> If an algorithm is defined to “throw an exception”, execution of the
>   algorithm is terminated and no result is returned. The calling
>   algorithms are also terminated, until an algorithm step is reached
>   that explicitly deals with the exception, using terminology such as
>   “If an exception was thrown…”. Once such an algorithm step has been
>   encountered the exception is no longer considered to have occurred.

Why is the exception no longer considered to have occurred after being thrown? I don't understand. There's an algorithm step "deals with" the exception, so I think it should be considered to have "occurred".

(I wanted to search the web before asking, but I didn't know what to search.)

Comment: If something is "caught" the application is no longer considered to be in an "exceptional" state. If it isn't caught, the exceptional state exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be explained with this sample code:

```
// our algorithm
function foo()
{
    // throw the exception
    throw 'a ball';
    console.log('this is not output'); // terminated statement
}

// the calling algorithm
function bar()
{
    try {
        foo();
    } catch (e) {
        // dealing with the exception
    }
    // no longer an exception here
    console.log('all is fine');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think they mean that in the context of the *step that deals with the exception*. In practical terms: a try-catch.

Once you catch an Exception it doesn't bubble up anymore.